# How can I compile .Net Micro Framework Porting Kit solutions?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, gcc, arm, .net-micro-framework

I have bought a ARM7S processor and I wanted to deploy the NETMF there. So I installed the .NETMF porting kit and a CodeSourcery GCC 4.6.3 compiler and tried to compile the solution for my processor.
I should say I have Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64, Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate installed on my PC.

At first I set debugger using this command: "setenv.cmd 4.6.3 C:\gcc" where I had installed my CodeSourcery ARM-EABI gcc compiler.
After that I had moved to folder "Solutions/--my CPU --/TinyCLR" and ran this command: "MSBUILD.EXE  /t:build /p:flavor=release;memory=flash"
It took some time and throw a huge amount of errors. I downloaded a older version of the compiler and only one error left.
So I opened a clear version of Windows 7 x86 (virtually) and installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional. After that I tried the same but the error was the same.

```
"c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Solutions\SAM7S_EK\TinyCLR\TinyCLR.proj" (build targe
t) (1) ->
(BuildAXF target) ->
  c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\tools\targets\Microsoft.SPOT.System.GCC.targets(325,
5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\gcc\bin\..\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe"  -stat
ic --gc-sections --no-warn-mismatch --library-path=c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Bui
ldOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\FLASH\release\SAM7S_EK\lib --library-path=c:\MicroFram
eworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib   --allow-multip
le-definition -u ARM_Vectors -u _start --Map c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutp
ut\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\FLASH\release\SAM7S_EK\bin\tinyclr.map --output=c:\MicroFram
eworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\FLASH\release\SAM7S_EK\bin\tinyclr.axf
 --script=c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\FLASH\release\SA
M7S_EK\bin\tinyclr_scatterfile.ldf c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\G
CC4.2\le\FLASH\release\SAM7S_EK\obj\Solutions\SAM7S_EK\TinyCLR\tinyclr_dat.obj
c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\FLASH\release\SAM7S_EK\obj
\Solutions\SAM7S_EK\TinyCLR\allocator.obj c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\
THUMB\GCC4.2\le\FLASH\release\SAM7S_EK\obj\Solutions\SAM7S_EK\TinyCLR\tinyclr.o
bj -( c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\li
b\Core.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\relea
se\lib\Hardware.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_ME
DIA\release\lib\InterruptHandler.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB
\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\HeapPersistence_stub.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v
4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\I2C_stub.lib c:\MicroFram
eworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\IOPort.lib c:\Mi
croFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\RPC_stub.
lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\
Serialization_stub.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY
_MEDIA\release\lib\Debugger.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4
.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\Debugger_full.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOut
put\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\Diagnostics_stub.lib c:\MicroFramewor
kPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\Graphics_stub.lib c:
\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\CorLib
.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib
\SPOT.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\releas
e\lib\SPOT_Messaging_stub.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2
\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\SPOT_Serialization_stub.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\
BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\SPOT_Hardware.lib c:\MicroFra
meworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\Messaging.lib c
:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\CLRSt
artup.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\releas
e\lib\CRC.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\ANY_MEDIA\re
lease\lib\WireProtocol.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le
\ANY_MEDIA\release\lib\SPOT_Hardware_SerialPort.lib c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\Bu
ildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\FLASH\release\SAM7S_EK\lib\tmp_tinyclr.lib c:\MicroFr
ameworkPK_v4_3\BuildOutput\THUMB\GCC4.2\le\FLASH\release\SAM7S_EK\lib\InteropAs
sembliesTable.lib -) -( "C:\gcc\arm-none-eabi\lib\thumb\libm.a" "C:\gcc\arm-non
e-eabi\lib\thumb\libc.a" "C:\gcc\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\4.2.1\thumb\libgcc.a" -)
 -( c:\MicroFrameworkPK_v4_3\tools\ads_v3_1\Lib\armlib\h_t.l c:\MicroFrameworkP
K_v4_3\tools\ads_v3_1\Lib\armlib\c_t.l -)" exited with code 1. [c:\MicroFramewo
rkPK_v4_3\Solutions\SAM7S_EK\TinyCLR\TinyCLR.proj]
```

Does anybody knows how to fix it or if there is a place, where I can find compiler CLR?
Thanks, 
Jonas